# Making a jQuery UI Slider with live()

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How can I code a Slider in jQuery UI to make it Live?

Here´s the code:

```
    //scrollpane parts
var scrollPane = $('.scroll-pane');
var scrollContent = $('.scroll-content');

//build slider
var scrollbar = $(".slider-vertical").slider({
    orientation: "vertical",
    value: "100",
    slide:function(e, ui){
        if( scrollContent.height() > scrollPane.height() ){ scrollContent.css('margin-top', Math.round( (100 - ui.value) / 100 * ( scrollPane.height() - scrollContent.height() )) + 'px'); }
        else { scrollContent.css('margin-top', 0) }
    }
});
```

I need to make it live()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [the livequery plugin](http://brandonaaron.net/code/livequery/docs) for this. Straight `.live` won't work here.

Answer (score 4):

I actually just had a similar issue and figured out how I can initialize my sliders using live() and a custom event.  This might help (if not Deryck, perhaps someone else):

```
$(".slider.minion").live('initMinionSlider', function () {
    $(this).slider({
        range: "min",
        value: 50,
        min: 0,
        max: 100
    });
});
```

Then just trigger the event manually whenever you want (I guess typically when the appropriate page/screen/view is being rendered):

```
$(".slider.minion").trigger('initMinionSlider');
```

Comment: This worked great and was much easier than Deryck's solution.

Comment: Thanks Kon. I solve this a time ago but I take note, off course. This kind of issues are recurrent, sometimes.