# jQuery .live() for GUI changer function

Tags: jquery

I use a nice way to make  collapsible  fieldsets using [Collapsible jQuery Plugin](http://michael.theirwinfamily.net/articles/jquery/collapsible-fieldsets-jquery-plugin-drupal-style):

```
$("fieldset").collapse();
```

Everything works fine while no fieldsets are added dynamically.
It is possible to bind events like 'click' using .live() function, I wonder if it's possible to automatically add .collapse() to all dynamically added fieldsets.

I tried:

```
$("fieldset").live('ready', collapse);
```

and

```
$("fieldset").live('ready', function () {
    $("fieldset").collapse();
});
```

But it doesn't work. Changing 'ready' to 'load' doesn't help too.

Is there any way to apply some UI goodies like ".colapse()" to new dynamically inserted DOM elements?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

jQuery .live() method needs some event to be triggered. It's not possible to use .live() or .delegate() to process newly added content through the AJAX callback.

In order to do so you need to use [livequery](http://brandonaaron.net/code/livequery/docs) plugin.

This [how to replace $.livequery with $.delegate or $.live](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-replace-livequery-with-delegate-or-live) forum thread describes the details of the problem and solution.

In my case the solution (with livequery plugin enabled) is:

```
 $('fieldset').livequery(function () {
     $(this).collapse();
 });
```

Works like a charm :-)

Comment: I disagree with this - "It's not possible to use .live() or .delegate() to process newly added content through the AJAX callback."  That's exactly what .live() does.

Comment: .live() needs some event to be triggered,  when you get some HTML from the server side - there is no such event. Quote from jQuery site: "Unfortunately, the way that you're using is the main purpose for liveQuery these days.  .live() and .delegate() are both wrappers around event delegation, which requires, well...an event to happen.  You can't do what liveQuery allows, which is an automatic callback run in the context of any elements that are added to the page, at the time that they're added."

Answer (score 1):

I had kind of a similar issue (kind of), so this may help you out...

[Making a jQuery UI Slider with live()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898115/making-a-jquery-ui-slider-with-live#6335777)

I basically had to initialize some elements with a jquery plugin using live() and a custom event.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped me to find the answer. The the livequery plugin does the magic!

Answer (score 1):

If it is dynamic, then why are you not attaching the collapse plugin to the DOM object after it is created?

```
var html = "<fieldset id='my-fieldset'></fieldset>";

$('body').appendTo(html);

$('#my-fieldset').collapse();
```

Comment: Dynamic in my case means it's HTML part returned from server side. HTML parts are added to a list and it's possible to add class only, not unique ID :(

Comment: @user118657, why can you not add a unique id? and if it is a class, then name the class something that is only used with collapse and say $('.to-collapse-object').collapse(); ... set the class so when the html is added you know that you can call that collapse(), and it wont matter how many times you call it hopefully the behavior is ignore if called multiple times.